# Swift generics, same function name for array vs single object possible?

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible to write a generic function that returns type `T` and one with the same name that returns `[T]` ?

Example:

```
    static func processResult<T: Decodable>(_ inputData: Data) -> [T] { ... }
    static func processResult<T: Decodable>(_ inputData: Data) -> T { ... }
```

So when calling I can do:

```
    let myObj: Car = processResult(data)
    ...

    let myObjs: [Car] = processResult(data)
```

I presume that technically `[T]` can also be considered a `T` type, hence the compiler getting confused. There isn't a way of saying that `T` will NOT be an array type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There isn't a way of saying that T will NOT be an array type?

Well, if you can a find a protocol `P` to which `Array` doesn't conform, but all the other `T`s that you want to use the second overload with *does* conform to, then you can do:

```
func processResult<T: Decodable>(_ inputData: Data) -> [T] {
    ...
}
func processResult<T: Decodable & P>(_ inputData: Data) -> T {
    ...
}
```

```
struct SomeStruct : Decodable, P { ... }

let x: SomeStruct = processResult(someData) // second overload
let y: [SomeStruct] = processResult(someData) // first overload
```

> Is it possible to write a generic function that returns type `T` and one with the same name that returns `[T]`?

Of course, you just need to pass in the type parameter explicitly to help the compiler infer what `T` is:

```
func processResult<T: Decodable>(_ inputData: Data, _ type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    ...
}
func processResult<T: Decodable>(_ inputData: Data, _ type: T.Type) -> T {
    ...
}
```

```
struct SomeStruct : Decodable { ... }

let x: SomeStruct = processResult(someData, SomeStruct.self) // second overload
let y: [SomeStruct] = processResult(someData, SomeStruct.self) // first overload
```

You might think that saying `SomeStruct` twice is long-winded, but it is very necessary here - without the first `SomeStruct`, it is ambiguous which overload you want to call, because the two overloads differ only in return type. Without the second `SomeStruct`, it is ambiguous what `T` is, because as you said, `T` can be an array too.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a chance to set the constraints in the function definition, you may also do this:

```
func processResult<T: Decodable & Collection>(_ inputData: Data) -> T { ... }
func processResult<T: Decodable>(_ inputData: Data) -> T { ... }
```

The compiler will always select the "most specialised" candidate. So, if your result type conforms to `Collection`, it's always the first candidate that gets selected.

Otherwise, if finds the other candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but you don't need to return [T], you can return only T, but you have to cast it like [Car]

```
func processResult<T: Decodable>(_ inputData: Data) -> T {
   return try! JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: inputData)
}

struct Car: Decodable {

}

let cars: [Car] = processResult(Data())
let car: Car = processResult(Data())
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I want the code in both cases to be completely different

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the **[Swift Language Source Code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5f6a074a760ff4f9ecb3164dbd904a2df54dd7e2/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L5422)**,

```
extension Array: Decodable where Element: Decodable { ... }
```

`Array` will be a `Decodable` if all its elements are `Decodable`. So if you try use generics, compiler only sees the protocol you are passing to the function as the `T` and that is the `Decodable` in your case.

So `T` will be seen as `some Decodable`

Also, `[T]` will be seen as `some Decodable`

#### To work around this:

You can mask the `Swift.Decodable`:

```
protocol Decodable: Swift.Decodable {}
```

So you code should work without need to any other changes.

---

<sub>p.s: I think Swift should infer it from the left side of an assignment operator or from the right side of a type casting automatically! But I know Swift developers are working hard to make these things happen and even one big enhancement of type inference is coming up with the Swift 5.4 after all these years!</sub>

Comment: Swift can "infer" the resulting type as long as you explicitly set it. How would you expect Swift to "infer" the resulting type based only on a Protocol that many object types might conform to?

Comment: It can infer the array of some protocol at least. Array is a type. Also it is a generic type that conforms to a protocol, not the protocol it self and we are telling the compiler which type we expect as we declare the variable. I think Swift can be powerful and smart enough to infer that and maybe it will be the only one that can do something like this.